# How to remove bullets from jquery multi select result

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Not sure if anyone encountered the same issues. I'm using multiselect bootstrap. However, it didn't work well for me. There are bullets on the dropdownlist, anyone knows how to remove it?

[Click here for the image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eByyM.png)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr-1.5.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/js/bootstrap-multiselect.min.js"></script>  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" type="text/css">
```

These are the scripts that I'm using! Thanks in advance :(

Comment: Please add your html as well so we can see what it is generating

Comment: .multiselect-container>li{list-style:none}

Comment: This is another css that I'm using, not sure if it is causing the issue sorry.... was trying to upload it.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzDjoq6bYax9SVA0TDVvckQ1ajQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this a few ways, place your CSS in between the `<head></head>` tags

## CSS

```
<head>
    <style>
        ul {
            list-style: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
```

## jquery

jquery will go in `<script></script>` tags in the header as well

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('ul').css('list-style', 'none');
});
```

Better to have a class associated with it so it does not affect all your lists.

Comment: Where do i put those comments sorry, been a while since i touched css

Answer (score 0):

```
.element-no-bullets {
    list-style: none;
}
```

Comment: You may either need to go a class up in your hierarchi or add !important `list-style: none !important;`

Comment: Post your HTML structure this is how you get it to work..Something is probably overwriting it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15134424)

Comment: It absolutely does @Robert